# Probability of a randomised algorithm solving SAT

Tags: satisfiability, randomness

Let WALKSAT be defined as follows:

Let $σ$ be a random truth assignment to the vars

For $t = 1, 2, . . . , 3n$:

◦ If $\phi$ is satisfied by $σ$, exit the loop

◦ Else, pick an unsatisfied clause $c$ and a var $x$ in $c$ uniformly at random

◦ Flip the value of $x$ in $σ$ (e.g., $x ← TRUE$ becomes $x ← FALSE$ )

Output $σ$

My lecture notes have a proof showing that $Pr[WALKSAT \space satisfies \space \phi] ≥ 1/(2 · 3^{n/2})$

But it mentions that with "more careful analysis" we can show that $Pr[WALKSAT \space satisfies \space \phi] ≥ (3/4)^n
/n$

I'm not sure how to prove this - I can't find anything about it online either.

Comment: This is Schöning's k-SAT algorithm, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.4067